# react-scrips: not found - Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am trying to create a build pipeline in Azure DevOps for my create-react-app project. However, when I run it I am getting the below error message during the npm install and build job.

```
2020-11-16T16:38:47.9641910Z npm ERR! Only absolute URLs are supported

2020-11-16T16:38:47.9906864Z 
2020-11-16T16:38:47.9908747Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2020-11-16T16:38:47.9910292Z npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2020-11-16T16_38_47_983Z-debug.log

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2879019Z 
2020-11-16T16:38:48.2879989Z > allpointsui@1.0.0 build /home/vsts/work/1/s

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2881040Z > react-scripts build
2020-11-16T16:38:48.2881441Z 

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2927383Z sh: 1: react-scripts: not found

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2967162Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2968631Z npm ERR! syscall spawn

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2969062Z npm ERR! file sh

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2971442Z npm ERR! errno ENOENT

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2983381Z npm ERR! allpointsui@1.0.0 build: `react-scripts build`

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2983876Z npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-11-16T16:38:48.2984513Z npm ERR! 

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2984827Z npm ERR! Failed at the allpointsui@1.0.0 build script.

2020-11-16T16:38:48.2985278Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2020-11-16T16:38:48.3029598Z 
2020-11-16T16:38:48.3032027Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2020-11-16T16:38:48.3033461Z npm ERR!     /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2020-11-16T16_38_48_298Z-debug.log

2020-11-16T16:38:48.3150378Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

2020-11-16T16:38:48.3205602Z ##[section]Finishing: npm install and build
```

Here is my YAML file for the pipeline.

```
trigger:
-master

pool:
`vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest`

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
inputs:
versionSpec: '10.x'
displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
npm install
npm run build
displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
inputs:
rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
includeRootFolder: true
archiveType: 'zip'
archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
replaceExistingArchive: true


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
inputs:
PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
ArtifactName: 'drop'
publishLocation: 'Container'
```

To resolve the error, I have tried doing npm i and npm audit fix which installed react-scripts4.0 but the error is still occurring. I have also seen a lot of people suggesting in other posts to delete the package-lock.json but we would prefer not do do that. Just another note: I can successfully run a build of the project on my local computer. Any suggestions or ideas of how to resolve this issue?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> react-scrips: not found - Azure DevOps build pipeline

First, try to check if `node_modules` directory exists in the Azure repo, if yes, remove it and then run npm install and build.

Second, add the entire path in the `package.json` to invoke react-scripts:

```
"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"
```

Instead of just: `"start": "react-scripts start"`.

If above not resolve your question, try to share your `package.json` in your question.

Comment: Thank you, this didn't completely solve it but it was one of the issues. We have since solved it!

Comment: How did you solve it, @DanaK?